# CSS Hover on INPUT.homeButton

Tags: css, input

I'd like to add a light hover over my buttons. Where do I begin?

```
INPUT.homeButton {
font-size: 12px;
color: #000;
font-family: Arial;
background-color: #FFF;
```

Comment: Try reading about the :hover pseudo-selector.

Answer (score 0):

Just use 'hover'. Add something like this to your CSS file:

```
INPUT.homeButton:hover {
    /* Your CSS properties (color, background-color, opacity, etc.) here... */
}
```

You can add 'opacity' property (1 = 100%, 0.5 = 50%, 0 = 0%, etc.) or change the 'color' and 'background-color' with light colors to make a similar effect.

Answer (score 0):

Just use :hover to achieve it.

```
input.homeButton:hover {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```